# Find the base value of a given number using recursion in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
def find_values(number, base, args=[]):
    if number // base != 0:
        args = args + find_values(number // base, base, args+[number % base])
        return args
    else:
        args = args + [number % base]
        return args

print(find_values(120, 10))
```

The function is suppose to take the number (as base 10) and change it to meet the given base value.

This is the best thing I have come up with so far. The array that's returned and printed has all three values that I need to be there but there is an extra 0 at index 0 for some reason and the array needs reversing, however, every time I attempt this in the else statement I get an error. Is there some way I accomplish this with my current code?

While I understand the principles behind recursion, I'm finding it very difficult applying it to this problem and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two mistakes:

- You are prepending your existing `args` list before new numbers; reverse these.
- When recursing you add the existing `args` list *twice*. Once as an argument to the recursive call, and again to the return value. Pick one or the other, not both.

The following version corrects both mistakes by only manipulating `args` in one direction:

```
def find_values(number, base, args=[]):
    if number // base != 0:
        args = find_values(number // base, base, [number % base] + args)
        return args
    else:
        args = [number % base] + args
        return args
```

which can be simplified to:

```
def find_values(number, base, args=[]):
    args = [number % base] + args
    if number // base:
        return find_values(number // base, base, args)
    return args
```

Instead of build the list as an argument, you can build it 'on the way out' as it were:

```
def find_values(number, base):
    args = [number % base]
    if number // base:
        return find_values(number // base, base) + args
    return args
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (simpler) approach using recursion would be:

```
def find_values(number, base):
    if number < base:
        return [number]
    else:
        return find_values(number / base, base) + [number % base]
```